# Eclipse CDT Kepler add new folder with header file to project

Tags: eclipse-cdt, include-path, eclipse-kepler

Hi again in theory an easy task but it keeps me making desperate.

I have a eclipse C project and if I add in the main project folder `ex1.h` I can
just `#include "ex1.h"` in the `main.c`. But if I create a new folder with a subfolder in the main project folder `mainProjectFolder/exercises/ex1/` then I have to include the header file like `#include "exercises/ex1/ex1.h"`

I thought "very easy task just add the folder" to the include path ... Had no effect

If I click on `Add Contributed` I can discover the include paths and the folder `C:\embARM7\workspaces\at91_sam7se512\arm_bootloadenv\exercises\ex1` is not there.

How can I add this folder to the `include Paths` ?
A problem is that in older posts with other versions of eclipse there where other options in the properties

Hope the picture helps to explain my concern
[image]